# Paypal Tracking IN GA doesnt work and code is messed

Tags: php, paypal, google-analytics, transactions

after two weeks of frustration. I have no clue yet what to do with this issue. since I have no access to the backend and its something not standard like WP or Open Source Code.

I am facing a common issue: Tracking correctly the transactions paid via Paypal, through Analytics.
For some reason it doesnt track properly, and I can not determine the source or flow and/or transaction IDs in GA.
There is a placement of the Google Tag Manager and GA / GU
BUt now the code has been messed up. GA and GTM are not working anymore.

Which in my belief is placed wrong, as it gives me a  conflict.

There is only one buy button shown here on this page: https://www.naturvel.com/checkout
When buying, it goes to paypal, as usual.after the redirection: it ends here: https://www.naturvel.com/confirmation

All i see in the GA backend is the following:  a four digit transaction ID, which I dont want, for all payments. the PayPal payments should be shown the transaction IDS from paypal source.

I have solved this issue before in a more dynamic environment, but not here.

Any ideas?

Comment: Google Tag Assistant says that the GTM account id is not valid, so this might be a place to start; also the dataLayer need to be above the GTM script.

Answer (score 0):

On your website, especially on your confirmation page the dataLayer is below your Google Tag Manager code, which means the earliest point GTM will see the data is when the DOM is loaded. I'm not sure it will read a dataLayer declaration at this point, usually you declare the dataLayer above the GTM snippet and use dataLayer.push({'key':'value') to add new data.

If you do not receive transaction data it's most likely because your tracking has already been executed before the data turns up in the code. Move the dataLayer before the GTM snippet and you should be fine.

Also Google Tag Assistant complains that your Account ID is not valid, but that might be just a quirk of the Tag Assistant (happens sometimes with unpublished containers).